How do I start my characters dream / What do I need to start my characters dream
I'm trying to write a backstory for my character but somehow I can't think of how or what place to start his dream because I'm currently new to writing stories

That's rather vague. Please explain what the dream has to do with the backstory and why you cannot simply narrate the dream in chronological order, from beginning to end.

Also, take a look at the related questions listed on the right →

A person's backstory doesn't have to be in the form of a dream. Indeed, dreams are usually about things that didn't really happen. Just say "He remembered his childhood in [place]" or simply "He had been brought up in [place]".

"Your question is a bit vague.
Before diving into the specifics of your story, let's establish a solid foundation through world-building. Pinpointing the setting is crucial. Is it a medieval realm or a futuristic landscape? What does this world look like?
Once you've defined the environment, other elements will naturally emerge. For instance, a post-plague era might feature scarce medicine, leading to a thriving herbal trade. Imagine a harsh winter in this world, with people falling ill and resources dwindling.
So, choose a time and place, paint a vivid picture of this world, and then introduce your story."
